# AirPlay API for macOS

Tags: objective-c, node.js, macos, electron, airplay

Is there currently any API (public/private) that will allow a 3rd party macOS app to mirror the mac desktop to a selected AirPlay receiver?
App Store distribution is off the table, so I'm open to private APIs at this point.

The story reads like so, "As a user, I want to click a button, connect to an AirPlay receiver, mirror my desktop without using the AirPlay button at the top of the screen."